# How to replace original text after a specific word at oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a message about unique OTP message like below at DB. I want to replace 7466 with 7**6 without breaking other parts. I tried to use `REGEX` and `INSTR` but it does not work any suggestion about the solution?
OTP codes have to be unique so at any message, the part I want to change are different. OTP code should not always coincide with the same place.

I have also three different types of message. So I don't store the OTP code in the column. It just existing in the message columns.

```
SELECT  id, SMS_TO_CUSTOMER  FROM CTB.CTB_SMS_HISTORY
WHERE 1 = 1 AND id = '51684'
```

**Original Text**:

Do not share your password.You have a one password that is 7466 with tax
69.9$, .......

**Expected Result**:

Do not share your password.You have a one password that is 7**6 with tax
69.9$, ........

like so ;

Message1:
Do not share your password.You have a one password that is 6**6 with tax
0.01$, .........

Message2:
............, 6**6 you must enter the verification code .............

Message3:
6**6 ...........  0.05$ o.............

Answer (score 1):

Use `REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT  id,
        REPLACE(SMS_TO_CUSTOMER, ' 7466 ', ' 7**6 ') AS sms_to_customer
FROM    CTB.CTB_SMS_HISTORY
WHERE   id = '51684'
```

or, for a dynamic code passed in to the query via the `:otpcode` bind variable:

```sql
SELECT  id,
        REPLACE(
          SMS_TO_CUSTOMER,
          ' ' || :otpcode || ' ',
          ' ' || SUBSTR(:otpcode, 1, 1)
              || LPAD('*', LENGTH(:otpcode) - 2, '*'
              || SUBSTR(:otpcode, -1, 1)
              || ' '
        ) AS sms_to_customer
FROM    CTB.CTB_SMS_HISTORY
WHERE   id = '51684'
```